# Redirect after "Mailchimp Popup" form submission

Tags: mailchimp

I have wordpress site where I successfully setup **Mailchimp Popup**. As default functionality of Mailchimp Popup, there is thank you message (which I can edit).

I also know how redirection work if I use embed form from Mailchimp.

But, my goal is, after that thank you message shown; I want my page to redirect to custom thank you page. `HTTP Redirection` Either using javascript or PHP or even from Mailchimp settings.

Let me know if that is possible in any way.

Thanks!